# Dynamic campaign name

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, custom-reports

I need a unique campaign name to match triggered send mails (e.g. journeys) in a further system (after export the report).

Therfore I had the idea to put a suffix on the campaign name. E.g. churnmail_Step1_YYYYMMDD

Is there a way to overwrite the standard value "campaign name" with a dynamic value like the date (e.g. in the AMP-initialization?

Comment: You cannot use dynamic values like the ones you proposed in Campaign names - but I do not fully understand your use case - can you please clarify what exactly you would like to achieve?

Comment: in the end I want to export via report all the sends, opens, clicks of the triggered sends. And here I want to have a unique Email name per day.  e.g. Winback20191129 for today / tomorrow Winback20191130 ...

Comment: And we are talking about SFMC Campaigns here (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ca_campaigns.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use dynamic values in Salesforce Marketing Cloud [Campaign](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ca_campaigns.htm&type=5) names.

As a workaround, you could build and automate your own reporting, tailored to your needs. In [Automation Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_automation_studio.htm&type=5), set up the following:

1. [SQL query](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) to pull tracking data from [Data Views](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/) into a Data Extension
2. You can add custom fields to that Data extension, eg. today's date and [concatenate](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5) it with an Email or Journey name using SQL
3. Set up a Data Extension [Extract Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_a_data_extract_activity.htm&type=5) and [transfer the file](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_file_transfer_activity.htm&type=5) to FTP, and grab it from there by your external system

This could all be automated and scheduled to run eg. daily or weekly or monthly.

Here's an example SQL query which pulls tracking data, that you can tailor to your needs:

```
SELECT 
getdate() as Today,
s.SubscriberKey,
j.EmailName,
jour.JourneyName,
ja.ActivityName,
s.EventDate as SentDate,
o.EventDate as OpenDate,
c.EventDate as ClickDate,
b.EventDate as BounceDate,
b.BounceCategory,
u.EventDate as UnsubscribeDate
FROM _Sent s LEFT JOIN _Job as j ON s.JobID = j.JobID
LEFT JOIN _Open o ON s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Click c ON s.JobID = c.JobID  and s.ListID = c.ListID and s.BatchID = c.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID and c.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Bounce b ON s.JobID = b.JobID and s.ListID = b.ListID and s.BatchID = b.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID and b.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _Unsubscribe u ON s.JobID = u.JobID and s.ListID = u.ListID and s.BatchID = u.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = u.SubscriberID and u.IsUnique = 1
LEFT JOIN _JourneyActivity ja ON s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
LEFT JOIN _Journey jour ON ja.VersionID = jour.VersionID
```